# how to Add a Button on the home screen in android?

Tags: android, button, android-widget

I want to add a button on the home screen and want to code in the click event of that button.
I have an application which has an activate button,As soon as this activate button is clicked i want that a Button gets created on the home screen and i want to code some database queries in its click event.I have already created that application,Now i want to place the button on the home screen.How do i do that.

Thanks in Anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can create a button on the Home Screen on-the-fly by coding.  In my book, the only way to get a button on the Home Screen is if the user adds it as a widget.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using xml layout for it add the button widget you needed and set it's visibility by   android:visibility="gone",when you clicked the first button  to activate the button to display,make it to visible by getting the id of the corresponding button 
  for eg: btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);